# Matplotlib embedded in wxPython: TextCtrl in Navigation toolbar not working on macos

Tags: macos, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm doing a simple embedded graph with Matplotlib APIs (2.2.2) in wxPython (Phoenix 4.0.1) and Python 3.6.4.  I have subclassed the WXAgg Navigation toolbar so I can remove the "configure subplots" tool and this is working fine.

In addition, I have added a read-only TextCtrl into my subclassed toolbar to show mouse coordinates (just like it appears in the pyplot state-based version of matplotlib).  I've implemented a simple handler for the mouse move events per the Matplotlib docs and this is all working fine on Windows 10.

However, this code does not fully work on macOS (10.13.4 High Sierra).  The graph displays just fine, the toolbar displays fine, the toolbar buttons work fine, but I don't get any display of my TextCtrl with the mouse coordinates in the toolbar (or even the initial value as set when I create the TextCtrl).

Can anyone shed light on why the TextCtrl in the Matplotlib toolbar doesn't work on the mac? Is there a way to do this on the mac?  And if this is simply not possible, what are my alternatives for showing the mouse coordinates elsewhere in my Matplotlib canvas?

Here's my sample code:

```
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx as NavigationToolbar

class MyToolbar(NavigationToolbar): 
    def __init__(self, plotCanvas):
        # create the default toolbar
        NavigationToolbar.__init__(self, plotCanvas)

        # Add a control to display mouse coordinates
        self.info = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, value = 'Coordinates', size = (100,-1),
                                style = wx.TE_READONLY | wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.AddStretchableSpace()
        self.AddControl(self.info)

        # Remove configure subplots
        SubplotsPosition = 6
        self.DeleteToolByPos(SubplotsPosition)
        self.Realize()

class Graph(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title='Coordinates Test'):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title) 

        self.SetSize((900, 500))

        # A simple embedded matplotlib graph
        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (8.2,4.2), facecolor = 'gainsboro')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, left = .12, right = .9, bottom = 0.05, top = .9, height_ratios = [10, 1], hspace = 0.35)
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        ax.plot(t, s)

        ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
               title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
        ax.grid()
        ax.set_navigate(True)

        # Get a toolbar instance
        self.toolbar = MyToolbar(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        # Connect to matplotlib for mouse movement events
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onMotion)
        self.toolbar.update()

        # Layout the frame
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def onMotion(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            xdata = event.xdata
            ydata = event.ydata
            self.toolbar.info.ChangeValue(f'x = {xdata:.1f},  y = {ydata:.1f}')
        else:
            self.toolbar.info.ChangeValue('')


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=""):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title) 
        self.SetSize((800, 480))

        self.graph = Graph(self)
        self.graph.Show()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title='Main Frame')
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is late, but I think that the simplest solution is to not subclass NavigationToolbar at all, but just to add a TextCtrl of your own.

That is, getting rid of your `MyToolbar` altogether and modifying your code to be

```
    # Get a toolbar instance
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)
    self.info = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, value = 'Coordinates', size = (100,-1),
                            style = wx.TE_READONLY | wx.BORDER_NONE)

    self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onMotion)
    self.toolbar.update()

    # Layout the frame
    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)

    bottom_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    bottom_sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
    bottom_sizer.Add(self.info, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(bottom_sizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

def onMotion(self, event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        xdata = event.xdata
        ydata = event.ydata
        self.info.ChangeValue(f'x = {xdata:.1f},  y = {ydata:.1f}')
    else:
        self.info.ChangeValue('')
```

will give TextCtrl that does display the motion events.

Comment: Yes, this would display the coordinates, but not subclassing the Navigation Toolbar eliminates the possibility to remove the subplots configuration tool.  And anyway, the proposed solution means a separate line of information below the toolbar which I'd like to avoid.  In the end, I decided to put the mouse coordinates in a StatusBar at the bottom and I moved the Matplotlib Toolbar to the top of my window layout.

Comment: Actually, the solution I gave does not add the text box with coordinates *below* the Navigation Toolbar, but puts it to the right of the Navigation Toolbar.     You might find wxmplot (wxPython + matplotlib) useful.  Its PlotFrame does not use a Navigation Toolbar at all, but does provide good Zoom (with zoom in/out history), save and print features, and has a configuration frame available for customizing colors, fonts, and so on.  Too many convenient features for basic 2D plots and display of false color images to list here.  See https://newville.github.io/wxmplot